# Error when uploading to S3 bucket using Presigned URL

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, axios

I followed [this AWS tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mw_-0iCVpUc&list=FLaQJkiB5-QM-bvoQwTFxxnA&index=1&ab_channel=AmazonWebServices) to create a bucket and a Lambda function that makes a request for a Presigned URL from S3. I also created an IAM role that has read/write permissions. I then created an API Gateway so I can call an endpoint. I then followed [this](https://medium.com/@kevinwu/client-side-file-upload-to-s3-using-axios-c9363ec7b530) tutorial to create a quick front-end in React. Its a simple drag/drop application that uses my API endpoint to get the Presigned URL. This is what my React component looks like:

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import { useDropzone } from "react-dropzone";
import axios from "axios";
import { API_ENDPOINT } from "./aws_config";

export function Test3() {
  const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles) => {
    var file = acceptedFiles[0];

    axios
      .get(API_ENDPOINT, {
        filename: file.name,
        filetype: file.type,
      })
      .then(function (result) {
        var signedUrl = result.data.signedUrl;

        var options = {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": file.type,
          },
        };

        return axios.put(signedUrl, file, options);
      })
      .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({ onDrop });

  return (
    <div
      {...getRootProps()}
      style={{ width: "400px", height: "300px", background: "#DDDDDD" }}
    >
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I try to upload a file however, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
    at isURLSameOrigin (isURLSameOrigin.js:57)
    at dispatchXhrRequest (xhr.js:108)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at xhrAdapter (xhr.js:13)
    at dispatchRequest (dispatchRequest.js:52)
```

I'm not sure what's wrong or how to even start considering I'm completely new to all this. The Lambda function is set up to only accept .JPG images which is what I uploaded. The file is only 15KB too so I don't think its the file that's the issue. Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Answer (score -1):

Could be a cors issue .
Also check if the retuned presigned url has http or https
Try with https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js